# Is increasing `max_hint_window_in_ms` to days a bad idea?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1, datastax-startup

I'm considering raising `max_hint_window_in_ms` to something like 72 hours. Anyone see issues with this? Essentially, it would allow us much longer downtime of nodes over a weekend without having to do a full repair.

Comment: Assume you'll have to consider your write / live data ratio as well as the absolut value of live data, to decide whether accumulating hints for longer period and then processing such would be lighter than doing a full repair consider repairs are recommended for cluster health before gc_grace anyway (default 10 days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version. After [C* 3.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6230) or DSE 5.0 when the hinted handoff storage was refactored its actually a very good idea to increase it. Before then (given your 2.1 tag assuming this is you) theres a lot of issues with accumulating too many hints highlighted in [this blog post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-coming-to-cassandra-in-3-0-improved-hint-storage-and-delivery). Unless using a version after 3.0 I would not recommend increasing it too much.

To highlight some pre 3.0 issues:

- Hints are stored in a C* table and acts like a queue which is a known antipattern, builds up many tombstones and slow/expensive reads
- Hints are partitioned by node, so if one node is down a long time the partition gets very huge. This is handled better in the latest of C*/DSE but particularly in 2.1 this impacts compactions, and gcs significantly.
- Compactions are called regularly and are required, but if there is nothing getting removed this means just rewriting the mutations over and over while the node is down (wasteful)
- Individual mutations need to go through memtables and full write path vs just appended to disk